# I'm failed to understanding array coordinate

Tags: unity

I'm totally lost in understanding the arrays' coordinates. Below is the code I use to generate an one dimensional `array(10)`. I attached the console result and the generated result.

Please explain why `array[0]` (the cube at the bottom) does not match the gizmos color? It looks like `array[0]` actually refers to the 2nd cube (counting from bottom) while `array[10]` has gone missing from the display. The lowest cube looks like an extra generated cube which is irrelevant to the gizmos color.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour

{
    int y;
    int[] array1 = new int[10];
    int temp;
    void Start()
    {
        
        for (y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                array1[ y] = Random.Range(0, 2);

                Debug.Log(string.Format("{0},{1}", y, array1[ y]));

            }
    }
    
    

    
    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
              
            for (y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                Vector2 pos1 = new Vector2(0,  y );
                Gizmos.DrawCube(pos1,new Vector3(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f) );
                Gizmos.color = (array1[ y] == 1) ? Color.black : Color.white;
            }
        
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gizmos.color` sets the colour of the **next** cube to be drawn so you need to call it before `Gizmos.DrawCube`.

```
for (y = 0; y < 10; y++)
{
      Vector2 pos1 = new Vector2(0,  y);
      Gizmos.color = (array1[y] == 1) ? Color.black : Color.white;
      Gizmos.DrawCube(pos1,new Vector3(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just realized Gregory explained this as one of my error in my previous post, just I failed to understand and aware of such mistake.